# jQuery - Strings and targeting

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've tried to google my question but it makes me even more confused. My question is:

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() < 200) {
          $("p").css("color", "red");
        } else {
          $("p").css("color", "green");
        }
    });  
}
```

Why do we write `(this)` and not `("this")` ?

How do I know if `(document)` and `(window)` should be written with `" "` - and why's that?

Maybe you could link me somewhere that explains my issue. My code apparently works either way, I'm just curious about the *why*.

Comment: Anything in `"` is a *string*.  You want a variable/object: `this`.  Same with `document` and `window` - they're objects.  When you do `$("selector")` you're passing a string, eg `"#myid"`

Comment: Wonderful! Is my code an anonymous function btw and why? I'd rather not post a new thread for this tiny question.

Comment: @HTML_Newbie please view my answer and mark it as the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript namespace, `this` is reserved [[source]](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).

The JavaScript object literal `this` refers to the inherited object from the present state in the current execution.

Another example of `this` we can see is when we are looping through an array and the object `this` would symbolize the current array object. You may, for example, see `this.title`, or `this.description` if we were iterating through a database array of blog posts.

`this` in jQuery refers to the inherited object. When we add the quotation marks, and it becomes a string, such as `"this"`. This makes jQuery parse it as a DOM selector.

Then we are now looking for the HTML DOM selector `<this>`, which to my knowledge, does not actually exist in the accepted HTML syntax standards.

As otherwise stated, the concept of `this` will become tricky when you are working in other JavaScript environments, such as React or Angular. Within the context of a functional component, `this` becomes the state, such as handling user sessions.